# How to get popular tweets from a user with tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to get popular tweets from a specific user with tweepy. I need something like result_type = 'popular' from the twitter API (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

With Python, try this to get 5 popular tweets with tag #yoursearch :

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#yoursearch',result_type='popular').items(5):
    print(tweet)
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not for a specific user

Comment: @mouses If you looked at the Twitter search syntax, you'd know that changing the variable `q` to something like `"from:twitterusername"` would return tweets for a specific user.